# Report Type to Capture Email of Users who made a Case Comment

Tags: reporting, case, case-comment

Is it possible create a report type of the comments made by a user capturing their email instead of their name?

In the default "Cases" report type, there are the `Case Comment Created By` and Case `Comment Created By Role` fields, but no additional fields to capture other user fields and since custom fields are not permitted on the Case Comment object, I do not believe there is a way to do this.

Is there any way to do this with native reporting functionality?

I know this is possible through SOQL and a VFP or LWC, but looking to rule out native capabilities.

Comment: wouldn't the email be the Case's Contact.Email?

Comment: In this use case you could have multiple SF user agents working on one case. Ex: user1@company.com could create a case comment and user2@company.com could create a case comment on the same case. Both could be created by two different John Smiths with same name and role, but different user emails.

Comment: Did you try a custom report type?  With lookup field: CaseComment.createdBy.Email

Comment: @cropredy There's the potential for the CaseTeamMember and the CaseContactRole Junction Objects to be involved here, thus the reason the Standard Report relies on Role (not to mention escalations that cause the owner to change). You're spot on that this needs to be done using a custom report if S.B. wants the report to using created by email address. He needs to create the same report and add the email fields using the relationships from these objects.